# Mailchimp mailing list custom segmentation

Tags: mailchimp, subscription, email, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am building [tech events](https://techevents.co/) aggregator website and I have subscription form where a user can enter his email and receive weekly popular events list for selected city.

[image]

So I need to segment emails by cities( one user can subscribe to multiple cities). Also for now it's about 2500 cities and list will grow dynamically. So need the ability to add cities/segments to mail service dynamically using API.

What is the recommended solution to add segments? I was thinking to use MailChimp groups, but the groups count per list is limited to(max 60 groups per list).

Also note: I am using Mailchimp now, but open to solutions with other services too.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? We're using static segments. You can create these segments and add members based on their mail address, via the API.
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/